# Produce nested selectors using SCSS loop?

Tags: sass

Can I use a loop (or recursion) in SCSS to produce something like this?

```
div {margin-top: 1px}
div > div {margin-top: 2px}
div > div > div {margin-top: 3px}
div > div > div > div {margin-top: 4px}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible with a loop and [selector-nest()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#selector_nest-instance_method) depending on your use case.

```
$sel: '';
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    $sel: if($i == 1, "div", selector-nest($sel, "> div")) !global;

    #{$sel} {
        margin-top: 1px * $i;
    }
}
```